# Consulta de colección que coincida con texto dado - Firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy tratando de obtener una lista de las colecciones de usuarios almacenados en `Firestore` que coincidan con el texto dado. La idea es esta:

> Teniendo = Usuarios: {Eduardo Perez, Jose Sanchez, Pedro Perez}

- 

> Al buscar: "Perez", quisiera obtener a los que coincidan: {Eduardo
> Perez, Pedro Perez}

Lo intento de esta forma:

```
Query query = database.Collection("Usuarios").WhereLessThanOrEqualTo("Usuario", Txt.Query);
```

**Pero escribiendo "Perez" me devuelve a todos los usuarios aunque no lleven "Perez" en el nombre.**

Ideas?

Comment: Editado para mejor entendimiento

Answer (score 1):

Tras varios años de ocupar firestore a nivel profesional, no he encontrado la manera de hacer un text query efectivo con las herramientas que te da firestore en ninguna tecnología (da un poquito igual pues los métodos que te da firestore para hacer queries son iguales sin importar el lenguaje).

Como lo señala su documentación, quizá quieras referirte a [Búsqueda en el texto completo en firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) y complementar con un tercero para hacer búsquedas avanzadas.

La solución rápida es que traigas un snapshot de toda la colección donde estas buscando, o de preferencia un snapshot refinado en donde quieres buscar e iterar con algun algoritmo de búsqueda. Debes de entender que esta solución no es escalable pues a mayores busquedas, mayores queries y mayor facturación, pero es eficaz.

Comment: Excelente workaround con la busqueda desde el lado de la app para mostrar exactamente al que se busca, pero a como tu dices, si cada vez que busque a un usuario tengo que cargarlos a todos sera un leak tremendo. Entonces, no hay forma de llamar de Firebase al menos a los mas parecidos?